How can I find intersection of four sphere without solving the system of equations?
s1 = Sphere[{3, 1, 0}, 3];
s2 = Sphere[{3, 6, 6}, 6];
s3 = Sphere[{4, 6, 2}, 5];
s4 = Sphere[{6, 2, 14}, 13];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], s1, s2, s3, {Cyan, s4}},  Boxed -> False]

By solving, I tried
solutions = 
 Solve[{(x - 3)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 0)^2 == 
    3^2, (x - 3)^2 + (y - 6)^2 + (z - 6)^2 == 
    6^2, (x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2 + (z - 2)^2 == 
    5^2, (x - 6)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z - 14)^2 == 13^2}, {x, y, z}]

Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Sphere[{3, 1, 0}, 3], Sphere[{3, 6, 6}, 6], 
  Sphere[{4, 6, 2}, 5], {Cyan, Sphere[{6, 2, 14}, 13]}, Red, 
  PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y, z} /. solutions]}, Boxed -> False]






Solve[Thread[p ∈ {s1, s2, s3, s4}], p]


{{p -> {1, 2, 2}}}


or

reg = RegionIntersection[s1, s2, s3, s4];
Solve[p ∈ reg, p]


{{p -> {1, 2, 2}}}


or

reg = RegionIntersection[s1, s2, s3, s4];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg];
dreg // InputForm
MeshPrimitives[dreg, 0]


{Point[{1., 2., 2.}]}


MeshRegion[{{1., 2., 2.}}, {Point[{{1}}]}]


To get the intersection point, you have to solve the equations, there is no other way. But you probably mean that you don't want to write them yourself, which is why you can use RegionIntersection. You'll get a BooleanRegion, which you can convert to an implicit form and let Mathematica solve it.
Solve@First@RegionConvert[RegionIntersection[s1, s2, s3, s4], "Implicit"]
(* {{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 2}} *)


s1 = Sphere[{3, 1, 0}, 3];s2 = Sphere[{3, 6, 6}, 6];
s3 = Sphere[{4, 6, 2}, 5];s4 = Sphere[{6, 2, 14}, 13];
FindInstance[{{x, y, z} \[Element] s1, {x, y, z} \[Element] s2, 
{x, y, z} \[Element] s3, {x, y, z} \[Element] s4},{x,y,z},2]


{{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 2}}


Shouldn't RegionIntersection[s1, s2, s3, s4] allow simplification of the FindInstance objective?

It makes a code more complicated,  doesn't it make? Also in order to find the intersection, that intersection is used. Thank you anyway for your interest to my answer.

How is one is-element-of condition more complicated than four is-element-of conditions?

@EricTowers:{{x, y, z} \[Element] s1, {x, y, z} \[Element] s2,  {x, y, z} \[Element] s3, {x, y, z} \[Element] s4} does not use any intersection explicitly to find the intersection of four spheres.  Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Still not seeing how " s1 = Sphere[{3, 1, 0}, 3]; s2 = Sphere[{3, 6, 6}, 6]; s3 = Sphere[{4, 6, 2}, 5]; s4 = Sphere[{6, 2, 14}, 13]; FindInstance[{x, y, z} \[Element]    RegionIntersection[s1, s2, s3, s4], {x, y, z}, 2]" is more complicated.

@EricTowers: I repeat because it uses RegionIntersection. Shorter is not identical with simpler. Sorry, I did my best and I don't see how to help you with understanding. That's all.
